# React Native API Call based on user location

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, expo

I have just started with react and react native My aim is to get the user location and based on the location co ordinates i will make a API call and display the results. Where have I went wrong? I am using an EXPO project with aqicn API library.

Here is the code.

```
import React,{ useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,Button} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import axios from 'axios';
//First get location - Done
//get latitude & longitude - Done
//Call the api with latitude and longitude
//Display results

export default function HomeScreen({navigation}) {

  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  //Lat and Long

  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
  const [longitude , setLongitude]= useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    (
      async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission Denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
      //Changes
      setLatitude(location.coords.latitude);
      setLongitude(location.coords.longitude);
            
    })();
  }, []);


    
    const la=latitude;
    const lo=longitude;
    
    console.log(la , lo);

    let res = fetch("https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:"+ la +";"+ lo +"/?token=ac3a71fc80931abd95ede14c2040f0678f578703")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json.data))
    .catch((error) =>console.log(error))
    
  

     console.log(data);
   

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}></Text>
    </View>
  );
}





   const styles= StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       padding:20,
       marginTop:15,
       margin:10,

     },
     paragraph : {
       padding:20,
       marginTop:5,
     }


   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is your problem. You must do the requests only when you have the latitude and longitude states filled. You ensure this using the hook useEffect. Your code must be like this:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    /** Creating an useEffect like this
you ensure that the latitude and longitude state are filled. Therefore,
your request is going to work :).
**/
    async function anyNameFunction() {
    let res = fetch("https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:"+ latitude +";"+ longitude +"/?token=ac3a71fc80931abd95ede14c2040f0678f578703")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json.data))
    .catch((error) =>console.log(error))
     console.log(data);
    }    
    anyNameFunction();
  }, [latitude, longitude]);
```

If you have any more doubts please fell free to ask more :). Waiting for your feedback and if the answer is correct please thumbs up!

Comment: Sir, its still not working. Its giving the error.
Invalid geo position - Can not parse 'null,null'
Invalid geo position - Can not parse 'null,null'

Comment: And one more thing, sir can we use two useEffects hook in one functional component?
For acheiving two different tasks.
Actually i am doing that only.
So if its wrong kindly correct me

Comment: Sure you can how many useEffects you desire. In your case, one is for when you mount your component you get the permission and get user location. The useEffect that I did is for when the latitude and longitude states get filled you request the API. Are you doing this request in iOS or Android? Remember to turn the location in the device too. Waiting for your feedback :).

Comment: Sir i am doing it on Android. And yes i did put the location on my device.
I am following your instructions and reciprocating the same. Still having some errors but the output is coming after few changes. Need few optimizations i think.
Anyways, thank you so much for your time and helping me learn. Thank you for guiding me sir..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm always here to help Sir! If you have more questions you can ask anytime :).